# Update database using foreach in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7

I want to insert new data in database using API, but first, i want to check the database using $po_transaction, it exist or not, if $po_transaction exist, do updated. But when i am input same data, it changed all data with one value

This is my database, when first insert:

[image]

and this is my database, when i am input same data (**This the issue**):

[image]

This is my controller:

```
public function post_data(Request $request){

        $po_transaction = $request->input('po_transaction');
        $data = $request->input('data');
        $decode_data = json_decode($data);

        if(!$decode_data){
            return response()->json(['message'=>'No Data','success'=>0]);
        }

        $po_id = Produk::where('po_transaction','=', $po_transaction)->first();

        // if po_id exist, update the data
        if ($po_id) {
            foreach ($decode_data as $item => $value) {
                DB::table('produk')
                    ->where('po_transaction', $po_transaction)
                    ->update(['po_transaction'=>$po_transaction, 'nama_produk'=>$value->produk, 'harga_jual'=>$value->price]);
            }

                return response()->json(['message'=>'success, data saved','success'=>1]);


        }else{
            // if po_id not exist, create new
            foreach($decode_data as $item => $value)
            {
                $saveTransaction = new Produk();
                $saveTransaction->po_transaction = $po_transaction;
                $saveTransaction->nama_produk = $value->produk;
                $saveTransaction->harga_jual = $value->price;
                $saveTransaction->save();
            }
            if($saveTransaction->save()){
                return response()->json(['message'=>'success, data saved','success'=>1]);
            }else{
                return response()->json(['message'=>'no data saved','success'=>0]);
            }
        }
    }
```

and for data, i am using json data like this:

```
[
  {"produk":"shampoo","price":"12000"},
  {"produk":"noodle","price":"110200"}, 
  {"produk":"cup","price":"1000"}
]
```

This is decode_data:

[image]

How to fix this issue, when i input same data, it not only change all data with one value?

Comment: can you show the value of `$decode_data`?

Comment: Currently, you are updating all the row presence inside the table you need a where clause (Maybe a unique value to update specific record )

Comment: @AnkurTiwari i have updated my question

Comment: Add line `->where('nama_produk', $value->produk) after `->where('po_transaction', $po_transaction)`or try to use your Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `method <model_name>::updateOrCreate()` to Create/Update in single method.

```
Produk::updateOrCreate(['po_transaction'=>$po_transaction,'nama_produk'=>$value->produk],['harga_jual'=>$value->price]);
```

for more info look at this https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify which record you actually want to update by proving the id in the `where` clause like this:

```
DB::table('produk')
  ->where([
    'po_transaction' => $po_transaction, 
    'id_produk'=> $value->id,
  ])
  ->update([
    'po_transaction'=>$po_transaction,
    'nama_produk'=>$value->produk,
    'harga_jual'=>$value->price,
]);
```

Comment: i don't put _id_ in my json data, so your code is error

Comment: I gathered as much, my point is that you need to! Otherwise, your SQL query applies to all records matched in your current WHERE clause.

Comment: @RahmatEffendi Please refer this answer, Pass id in your json code and use in your code with where.